# The simplest way for creating 2D matrix in loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, vector

I would like to know how to create matrix from vector in loop in the simplest possible way. I have for cycle which contains conditions (so i don't know the final shape of the matrix) under which I want to append a vector to matrix (it should be empty at the beginning). I would like to do something like:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(100):
   vector=np.random.random(10)
   condition=np.random.choice([True, False])
   if (condition):
      matrix[i,:]=vector
```

In matlab this is super easy (the written example (in matlab syntax ofc) works perfectly). However python has much more (at least for me) complicated system with arrays and lists. So, if anybody knows the simplest and most correct way how to do this in python, please give an example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could make `matrix` a python list and then use `.append()` to add `vector`. Then after your loop call `np.array(matrix)`

```
import numpy as np

matrix_as_list = []

for i in range(100):
   vector=np.random.random(10)
   condition=np.random.choice([True, False])
   if (condition):
      matrix_as_list.append(vector)

matrix = np.array(matrix_as_list)
```

I'm not sure about Python, but in MATLAB it would be faster to actually initialise your matrix to be a `100`-by-`10` matrix and then delete the unnecessary rows afterwards rather than growing the matrix in a loop. Of course, fastest would be to just vectorize the solution to not use a loop at all.

Comment: thanks a lot! I hoped that there is a solution, just to work with arrays - not to converting to list and then back.

Comment: Could you also be more specific about "vectorize the solution to not use a loop at all"? Thanks

Comment: Why not use lists? My solution only converts once btw

Comment: Full vectorization will depend entirely on your use case. If this example is what you want to actually do, then choose a random integer between `0` and `100`, let's call it `k` and now `matrix` is just a `np.random.random(k,10)`, no loop